# Why am I getting a constructor error when opening a Keras yaml model using model_from_yaml?

Tags: python, keras, yaml

I am trying to load a CNN model I built on Kaggle in my desktop using YAML, but I am facing an error -

> ConstructorError: could not determine a constructor for the tag 'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object/apply:tensorflow.python.training.tracking.data_structures.ListWrapper'
> in "", line 53, column 13:
> axis: !!python/object/apply:tensorflow ...

The code I used is -

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_yaml

yaml_file = open('model.yaml', 'r')
loaded_model_yaml = yaml_file.read()
yaml_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_yaml(loaded_model_yaml) <------------- Error occurs at this line
# load weights into new model
loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
print("Loaded model from disk")
```

Comment: i don't know what CNN/Kaggle are, but if I'm guessing right, the module you are using uses PyYAML and was apparently not updated to [its latest changes](https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/wiki/PyYAML-yaml.load(input)-Deprecation). Due to security reasons it needs to use `UnsafeLoader`. File a bug report for `tensorflow.keras.models` I'd say